# Navigation Back to previous activity in android

Tags: android

I am trying to navigate back to previous activity with the UP back button in `ActionBar` but it doesn't work properly. I have

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in

```
 onCreate()
```

method and in

```
onOptionsItemSelected
```

I have

```
if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
                onBackPressed();
            }
```

On emulator it works fine. When i install the application on my mobile, then  the back button is gone.
Any ideas how to fix that issue?
Part of my Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<activity
            android:name="datepicker.DatePicker"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_date_picker" >
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="gridviewcontext.TableItem"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_table_item" >
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Comment: What is the API level in you mobile and AVD? Post the manifest file also.

Comment: If you are using ActionBarCompat consider use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: ok i edited the question. how do i know which api level do i have on mymobile? i have the jellybean i think (4.0 android)

Comment: Show your relevant xml file that contains code for `UP back button`.

Comment: @c_user89: In your mobile, go to `Settings->about device` and then see `Android Version` number.

Comment: on my mobile i have android version 4.1.2

Comment: @c_user89: Your mobile is of `API 16` so you have to add the required metadata in order to support `up navigation`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the parent activity name in the activity you enabled the back button in your manifest:

```
android:parentActivityName="your_parent_activity"
```

Comment: yes but the parent of the activity is not always the same. I may navigate to from one activity to other with different ways. so i cannot have parent

Comment: @c_user89 did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are testing the app in a mobile with version less than API level 16.

If your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support Library with your app and add a  element inside the `<activity>`. Then specify the parent activity as the value for `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY`, matching the `android:parentActivityName` attribute.Do as follows,

```
<activity
        android:name="myomega.datepicker.DatePicker"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

in your manifest file, you are missing `android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"` this line.

refererence http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: If your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support Library with your app....
it is correct

Comment: the parent of the activity is not always the same. I may navigate from one activity to other with different ways. so i cannot have parent. or can i ?

Comment: @c_user89: see the last section of the documentation from the reference link that I have mentioned.Might be helpful.

Comment: well i added to my manifest android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" and i changed onBackPressed() to the code according to the last section in the link you provided me. But now it takes me back me always to the MainActivity(as described in manifest) and not to the previous actvity

Answer (score -1):

Use finish() instead of onBackPressed()

Comment: can you say difference between finish() and onBackPressed()?

Comment: Does it answers OP's question - "When i install the application on my mobile, then the back button is gone" ?

Comment: if you have not Override onBackPressed() method from your Activity then, it will invoke finish() for your Activity. You don't need to call finish() explicitly..

So by that it will display Activity which is in the top of the Activity Stack. And there is empty Stack then you will quite from the application.

If you have Override onBackPressed() method then You have to call finish() explicitly to destroy activity.

Comment: Just try with finish()

Comment: finish or onBackPressed() had the same result for me. The problem is that on my emulator the up back button exists and works fine. But on my mobile the navigation up (back) button isn't displayed